# search method names in assembly

Tags: c#, static-analysis

If I have code like below in C# where MyClass is some class in a library in the project. How can I do static analysis and find out how many times in the code Method1 and Method2 are called.

Output should be: namespace.MyClass.Method1 = 4, namespace.MyClass.Method2 = 1

```
namespace.MyClass obj = new namespace.MyClass()
obj.Method1();
obj.Method2();

namespace.MyClass obj2 = new namespace.MyClass()
obj.Method1();
obj.Method1();
obj.Method1();
```

Thanks,
D.

Comment: The way you declare the problem it seems you don't need reflection at all (while it looks like you're trying to use it). Just define a (perhaps) global dictionary and every time a method is called increase the corresponding entry in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, click right on your method and select "Find All References".

Comment: I actually need to do it in code as part of static code analysis to do some analytics on the code based on how certain classes and methods are being used.

Comment: As you want to intercept the method calls, you are looking then for Aspect-Oriented Programming. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio Professional edition or upper, you can use Instrumentation profiling in order to collect information about your process. Among them there will counter which determines how many times particular function has been placed on the stack (how many times was the function called).

More on instrumentation profiling
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182369.aspx

Other option, if you just need the counts, you can place a log call at the beginning of your methods (using Trace class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx or some 3rd party library like log4net) and count method calls from log file after execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) to write a C# LINQ query to see which method is calling which other method.

```
from m in Application.Methods
select new { m, m.MethodsCallingMe }
```

[image: NDepend methods callers]

You can also right-click a particular method and generate a query to get callers of this method:

[image: NDepend particular caller method, generating code query]

The result is:

[image: NDepend particular caller method]

Notice in the screenshot above you can also generate a C# LINQ query to get all callers (transitive) of a method (Menu **Select methods that are using me (Directly and Indirectly)**). In such case case the query result is exportable to a dependency graph, and you can see transitive callers of your method.

[image: NDepend transtive callers of a method]

The [call graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Call) can look like:

[image: NDepend transtive callers graph]

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*